# Aggregation queries on millions of nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to query ~8 million nodes in a neo4j database.  I can do queries which hit the index for exact matches easily enough, but is there a performant way to do aggregations?

```
MATCH (r:Resident) RETURN r.forename, count(r.forename) ORDER BY count(r.forename)
```

This query just sits there until I eventually restart my server.  I've read the performance guides and I'm watching vm_stat and it seems to be quickly running out of pages free.  I've tried tuning the memory / JVM heap settings to various things, but I'm not sure I completely know what I'm doing ;)  I've got an 8 GB MacBook Air with an SSD drive in case that's helpful for suggesting settings.  Also, here's my stats on my DB from webadmin:

```
10,236,226 nodes

56,280,161 properties

10,190,430 relationships
2 relationship types

14,535 MB database disk usage
```

Comment: A limit will help--otherwise it needs to build up a result set of your entire list of names and their counts.

Answer (score 0):

I inserted 8M nodes with just 1 prop, and got this query down to ~20s without changing the default settings (after warming up the cache--first time took 90s), which is comparable to other databases like postgres (which I also tested).

Some things you could try to do:

- raise the sizes on the appropriate files mmio settings (as per the file sizes in data/graph.db/) in conf/neo4j.properties (at the top)
- increase the node cache size in neo4j.properties
- increase the heap init/max in neo4j-wrapper.conf
- make sure you have enough RAM left over